# How to choose a continuous function which vanishes **only** on the closed set

Tags: gn.general-topology, continuity, compactifications, paracompactness, coarse-geometry

We are reading John Roe's book *Lectures on Coarse Geometry*. We come across a question in P27 line 9:
    Suppose $X$ is a paracompact and locally compact Hausdorff space, $\bar{X}$ is a compactification of $X$, how to use Urysohn's Lemma to choose continuous functions $f,g:\bar{X}\times\bar{X}\to \mathbb{R}^+$    such that $f$ vanishes **only** on the diagonal of $\bar{X}\times\bar{X}$, and $g$ vanishes **only** at infinity (that is, on $\bar{X}\times\bar{X}\backslash X\times X$)?

If  $\bar{X}\times\bar{X}$ is perfectly normal, or the diagonal and the infinity are both $G_\delta$ sets, we can have that according to P213 in  Munkres's book *Topology*. But we fail to verify the condition(we are not familiar with paracompact Hausdorff space).

Or  any other way?

Comment: This question is not fit for MathOverflow, but would find a very good home on Math.SE. Flagged it for migration.

Comment: A note to potential voters: despite the wording, the offending text in Roe’s book is not posed as a question or exercise or some such, it is in fact in the middle of a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The function $f:\bar X\times \bar X\to\mathbb R$ exists if and only if the compactification $\bar X$ of $X$ is metrizable, which implies that the locally compact space $X$ is metrizable and separable.

This follows from a well-known metrizability theorem saying that a  compact topological space $K$ is metrizable if and only if the diagonal is a closed $G_\delta$-set in $K\times K$.

2. The function $g:\bar X\times \bar X\to \mathbb R$ exists if and only if the set $X\times X$ is of type $F_\sigma$ in $\bar X\times \bar X$, which happens if and only if the locally compact space $X$ is $\sigma$-compact if and only if $X$ is Lindelof.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a continuous real-valued function that vanishes only on the diagonal, then that easily implies that the diagonal is $G_\delta$ in $\overline{X}^2$.  We can then intersect with $\overline{X}\times\{a\}$ to see that $\{a\}$ is $G_\delta$ in $\overline{X}$, for every $x\in\overline{X}$.  There are certainly examples where this is not true.  For example, we can let $\omega_1$ denote the first uncountable ordinal, and take $\overline{X}=[0,\omega_1]$ with the order topology.  This is the one-point compactification of the space $X=[1,\omega_1]$, which is homeomorphic to $\overline{X}$.  We then find that $X$ is compact Hausdorff (and so is certainly locally compact Hausdorff and paracompact) but $\{\omega_1\}$ is not $G_\delta$.

Comment: Why is the intersection with $\bar{X}\times \{a\}$ $G_\delta$? Note that $\bar{X}\times\{a\}$ is not open.

Comment: I did not claim that $\overline{X}\times\{a\}$ is $G_\delta$ in $\overline{X}\times\overline{X}$.  Please think about the argument more carefully.

Comment: You say the **intersection** is $G_\delta$, right?

Comment: No, I did not say that.  Please think about the argument more carefully.

Comment: In my book, a compactification is required to have the property that the original space is *dense* in it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek If you want you can take $X=\overline{X}\setminus\{\alpha\}$ for any countable limit ordinal $\alpha$ and then $X$ will be dense in $\overline{X}$.

Comment: Yes. In fact, there is nothing stopping me from taking $X=\overline X$.